# Can I control the DateTime format displayed by my cmdlet?

Tags: datetime, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I own a cmdlet with a DateTime property that represents the timestamp of an event on a server.  The cmdlet reads a log on the server and outputs some information.  Since a bunch of events can happen in a short window, millisecond precision is important for users of the output.

However, when using format-list or format-table, the output only shows the seconds, e.g. `4/15/2015 5:31:30 PM`.  I would prefer to use the [fff time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#fffSpecifier) instead.

I know that the actual data aren't rounded because if I query the Millisecond property on my DateTime value, I see the correct value.  For example, for a given output `$event`, if my log line has the timestamp `2015-04-16T00:31:30.525Z`, `$event.Timestamp.Millisecond` returns 525.

Is there something I can do in my cmdlet to specify the DateTime should be displayed with milliseconds?  For example, when the user types:

```
> Get-LogInfo | ft
```

I want to show by default:

```
Timestamp              EventData
---------              -------
4/15/2015 17:31:28.525 (data)
```

I'd also like similar behavior for format-list.  Ideally users of the cmdlet wouldn't have to do any extra work to see the milliseconds.

Comment: What's wrong with adding a property solely for display? DateTime already does that, actually. Similarly, I would add an extended script property to the event objects for display. The only other methods I know of that can change how they are displayed will affect all DateTimes in the current session/process (e.g. messing with DateTimeFormatInfo's LongTimeFormat).

Comment: @mikez I'm worried about confusion with having two time properties if someone pipes the output to Format-List.  I already have a lot of properties (more than I'd like) and removing the DateTime version would be a breaking change for some of my users and consuming tools.  I need to support a rather diverse audience.

Comment: @Troyen Consider defining a default display property set if you've got too many properties.

Answer (score 6):

You can ask `Format-Table` to convert `DateTime` to string however you want:

```
$t = New-Object psobject -Property @{Text ="test"; dt = (Get-Date)}
$t | ft Text,@{expression={"{0:HH:mm:ss.fff}" -f $_.dt};label="time with milliseconds"} -AutoSize
```

prints:

```
Text time with milliseconds
---- ----------------------
test 18:08:51.725
```

Alternatively, you can set up current thread's long time pattern to show milliseconds:

```
$t = New-Object psobject -Property @{Text ="test"; dt = (Get-Date)}
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = 'HH:mm:ss.fff'
$t | ft * -AutoSize
```

prints:

```
Text dt
---- --
test 4/21/2015 10:24:08.877
```

Latter, obviously, affects all date to string conversions, so use with care.

Answer (score 1):

Both `Format-Table` and `Format-List`(less often) will change object properties and types silently. They should be one of the very last things you do to tidy up information for display. Depending on where you have those in your script, they could easily be the culprit for your issue.

What stands out to me in what you're saying is:

> The milliseconds are out of order.

This tells me your object property is NOT actually a `DateTime` object by the time you're attempting to sort it. You're seeing the effects of "alphabetical" sorting vs. "numeric" sorting.

Short example:

```
PS C:\>$ints = 5200,310,560,290
PS C:\>$strings = "5200","310","560","290"
PS C:\>$strings | Sort-Object
290
310
5200
560
PS C:\>$ints | Sort-Object
290
310
560
5200
```

For specifically converting a `DateTime` to the fff notation:

```
PS C:\>(get-date).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff")
04/20/2015 18:01:22.710
```

I've used a format that includes leading zeroes for single digit months/minutes/hours, etc... to reduce risk of alphabetic sorting behaving differently than numeric sorting. Similar note to the above, it would be better to make sure sorting occurs before any other formatting activity to get the most accurate results.

If this isn't enough to help sort out the issue, it would help to see some of the script/code. Specifically the part that generates the object that contains the `DateTime` property and what is done with it before sorting it.

Comment: I was mistaken on the sorting, but removed that bit because my primary goal is to find out if I can influence Format-Table and Format-List.  My cmdlet is being piped directly to ft or fl by my users to display a batch of results.

Comment: Well, in that case, I kinda like n0rd's answer as another option. :)